# How to scrape email id from anchor tag without opening email application

Tags: javascript, c#, html, cefsharp

I'm trying to develop windows based web scraper using HAP, CefSharp, and C#. I dont have deep knowledge of handling DOM and HTML.

By any means, is it possible to **scrape email id** (or just **copy the email id to clipboard**) in the following link **without opening email client or new tab**.

```
<a class="classAuthorEmail" href="mailto:" aria-label="Mail Option">email</a>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hi, I'm not too clear what you want. Is this copying to be done by Javascript? And what do you mean by "email id" - is it the value of href or...?

Comment: What "_**email id**_"?

Comment: sorry for my english... anchor tag has no email id but it just shows "mailto:" option. but when clicked it opens mail application. i need to scrape the href value, which is an emailid. here is sample link https://www.hindawi.com/journals/aag/2021/1198341/.

Comment: By default in CefSharp mailto links don't do anything,  you can intercept the link click see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#protocol-execution for example. You don't have to call Process.Start you can do whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

To work with the DOM you will need the querySelectorAll.

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll("[href^='mailto'");
```

for example, for the link,

```
<p><a href="mailto:someone@example.com">Send email</a></p>
```

You will get : `mailto:someone@example.com`

To keep with JavaScript you can use the following:

```
var mails = [];
for (var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {
  var el = els[i];
  mails.push(el.href.replace(/mailto:/gi, ''));
}
```

Comment: but you can see there is no email id at href. it just shows "mailto:". I think it needs to be caught while invoking the class of the anchor tag or while executing the script. how to achive that

Comment: I was thinking this is example. If there is no email it probably invoking this by a JavaScript, so you need your scraping will allow the JavaScript to run.